# Can my iPhone have more than one iCloud account on it at a time?

Tags: iphone, icloud

Can I add more than one iCloud account to an iPhone?  For example if I set my wife and I both up with an iCloud account, could I get her calander and mine on my phone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### No - the **iCloud** section of the Settings app only allows for one account on iOS 5.

You can however add as many iCloud accounts to the **Mail, Contacts, Calendars** as you have time to set up. You will see that you can enable the majority of the services on each subsequent non-main iCloud account.

The following items work only on the main account:

- **Backup**
- **Documents & Data**
- **Photo Stream**

The following item is exclusive - any one (but only one) account can have:

- **Find My iPhone**

For example, I use one iCloud account as my primary personal account and have a second account for a consulting business. Here is what that non-main account looks like when set up.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes but the non primary account is limited to only a few services. Simply add a new account to the mail, contacts and calendars section of settings, and tap iCloud

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is to share iCloud calendars, you can easily do this from the iCloud calendar web app. Each calendar in the sidebar has a "share" icon next to it. Simply click this and enter the name of the person you want to share with.