# Can I create an iCloud account with a borrowed IOS5 device?

Tags: snow-leopard, ios, icloud

An IOS5 device is needed to create an iCloud account. I have a Macbook and an iMac both running Snow Leopard, but no IOS device nor a mobile.me account. I want to use iCloud's calendar features.  I know SL doesn't officially support iCloud (yet) but there seem to be work-arounds (and the odd rumor of SL support coming later, but I won't hold my breath) and I want to try to bring it up now.

I'm interested in whether someone with an IOS5 device can use it to open an iCloud account, give it over to me, and then *completely remove it from their device* without either crippling the account or leaving the device or the account connected to the other.  (This is a question, BTW, not a request for someone to do it).

[This question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/35212/can-my-iphone-have-more-than-one-icloud-account-on-it-at-a-time) discusses having several iCloud accounts on one device, but not abandoning an account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that an IOS5 device isn't required; you can create the account with a computer running Lion.  The trick is to create yourself an Apple ID (I used iTunes but there may be other ways, perhaps a free Developer account?). Then use Lion's iCloud pane to create an iCloud account with the ID. With iCal, create an iCloud calendar.  Now delete the calendar from the Lion machine. Buy the Lion machine's owner a beer or flowers as appropriate, or thank the Apple store genius. :)

Go to your Snow Lion machine, log into iCloud.com and change the account password.

Answer (score 1):

While you should be able to use an iOS 5 device to convert to iCloud, you can upgrade your MobileMe account to iCloud on a Snow Leopard machine at the following link:

https://www.me.com/move/

Comment: I'm specifically asking about the IOS device (that creates the account) being able to completely detach from it so I could take over the account. Thanks, though.